# Creating a custom field

Tags: custom-controls, vaadin

I have the following container :

```
BeanContainer<Integer, Person> container = new BeanContainer<Integer, Person>(Person.class);
container.setBeanIdProperty("lastName");
```

Where person has a "lastName", "firstName" and "town" attributes.

I'm passing this container to my table :

```
table.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

The problem is that I want to have a bean id property value (called "fullname") that is the result of the lastname and firstname concatenation.

How can I do this wit the setTableFieldFactory and createField methods ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is to add a getter method getFullName() to your Person class which concatanes and than returns the name+surname fields

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need a simple autogenerated column. Here is a sample: http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/versions/6.1/src/com/vaadin/demo/featurebrowser/GeneratedColumnExample.java

Answer (score 0):

fmucar is right.

do not forget to include a setter too. 
In some case a Property.ReadOnlyException will be throw if you miss to include a setter.

If you can do not use GeneratedColum because of the folowing point :

- the visible display will be regenerated at any interaction (to try this you can add a generated column who return a random number).
- the container know only the visible part. So sorting could be tricky.